# Before long vs soon

Tags: word-meaning

These two words have the similiar meaning in my native language. Is there actual difference between them? For instance:

> It's going to snow before long.

and

> It's going to snow soon

I'm not sure in the latter example at all.

Comment: They are pretty much identical in meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have identical meaning. `Before long` is poetic (and maybe slightly archaic). I imagine my grandfather saying it. It can be abbreviated `'ere long` to be even more poetic.

[Shakespeare's 73rd sonnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonnet_73) ends:

> This thou perceiv'st, which makes thy love more strong,
>
> To love that well, which thou must leave ere long.

So in common usage, I'd stick with `soon`.

Comment: But "*before ya know it*" is still quite common.